# Grouping data but from the same source - MYSQL

Tags: mysql

This is my tabel, relation with dependent

> Table: **data_mustahik**

```
+---------+---------------+------------+
| nama    | nomor_kk      | kepala_kel |
+---------+---------------+------------+
| 11      | 11            | 1          |
+---------+--------------+-------------+
| 12      | 12            | 1          |
+---------+--------------+-------------+
| 13      | 12            | 0          |
+---------++---------------+-----------+
| 14      | 12            | 0          |
+---------+--------------+-------------+
| 15      | 11            | 0          |
+---------+--------------+-------------+
```

> Table: **data_survey**

```
   +--------------+---------------+
   | id_survey    | nomor_kk      |
   +--------------+---------------+
   | 21           | 11            |
   +--------------+---------------+
   | 22           | 12            |
   +--------------+---------------+
   | 23           | 12            |
   +--------------+---------------+
   | 24           | 12            |
   +--------------+---------------+
   | 25           | 11            |
   +--------------+---------------+
```

> Table: **rekapitulasi_kelayakan**

```
+--------------+---------------+
| id_srv       | kelayakan     |
+--------------+---------------+
| 21           | layak         |
+--------------+---------------+
| 22           | tidak         |
+--------------+---------------+
| 23           | -             |
+--------------+---------------+
| 24           | -             |
+--------------+---------------+
| 25           | -             |
+--------------+---------------+
```

**OUTPUT NOW (FALSE)**

```
11 | 11 | Layak 
12 | 12 | Tidak
13 | 12 | - 
14 | 12 | -
15 | 11 | -
```

**I want to OUTPUT THIS (RIGHT)**

```
11 | 11 | Layak 
12 | 12 | Tidak
13 | 12 | Tidak 
14 | 12 | Tidak
15 | 11 | Layak
```

I'm stuck to query this .. Actually this query so long .. its just simple .. 
If i using group .. the output just one not all appear ..

```
i want to grouping 
nomor_kk 11 with nama 11,15 => layak
nomor_kk 12 with nama 12,13,14 => tidak
```

my query is

```
SELECT * FROM data_mustahik dk
         INNER JOIN data_survey ds 
         ON dk.nomor_kk=ds.nomor_kk
         INNER JOIN rekapitulasi_kelayakan rk
         ON ds.id_survey=rkid_srv
```

Comment: Does `normor_kk` contain only these two values `layak` and `tidak`?

Comment: yes just two values @Viki888

Answer (score 0):

Try using `case` in `select` statement like below

```
case 
 when nama in (11,15) and ds.nomor_kk = 11 
  then 'Layak' 
 when nama in (12,13,14) and ds.nomor_kk = 12 
  then 'Tidak' 
end as kelayakan
```

Hope this should help you out.

Comment: my data dynamic ?

Comment: What do you mean?